# HTML PNG as ICO without conversion

Tags: html, header, png, ico

I want to use a png as an ico in html, how could I go by doing this? I can you can use a png by some code such as:

```
<link rel="ico" type="png/ico" href="link"/>
```

What is the correct way to use a png as an iso with out converting it to an actual ico?

Answer (score 4):

You can't use a PNG as an ICO. They are different file formats.

You can specify that the Favicon is a PNG image, and the syntax is exactly the same as for any other Favicon except that the type is the PNG type.

```
<link rel="icon" 
      type="image/png" 
      href="http://example.com/myicon.png">
```

Since a PNG isn't an ICO, the [browser needs to support](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon#File_format_support) PNG images as Favicons for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

Icons are just Bitmaps... You could just use one of these converters. Check out this question:

[How to convert .ICO to .PNG?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37590/how-to-convert-ico-to-png)